# Kali Linux black box when clicking on "Graphical install:

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot

OK, so I have a dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04.0 and Windows 11. I want to add Kali Linux to make it a triple boot. However, after flashing Kali Linux onto my 8GB USB pendrive, I can't boot into graphical install. It shows a black box. Note that I don't have a CD-ROM/DVD drive, plus I'm stuck on UEFI/GPT because of Windows 11. Also, my ISO version is 2018.2. If getting the latest ISO is the only way to go, I will do that, but if there are any other workarounds, please leave them below.

My specs:

Operating System: Microsoft Windows 11 Home (64-bit)
Model:       HP Laptop 15-dy2xxx
Motherboard: HP 87FE
Memory:      7.65 GB -1MHz
Northbridge: Intel ID9A04 01
Southbridge: Intel IDA082 20
BIOS: AMI F.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CPU which is Intel Core i5-1135G7 was released in the past 18 months or so, version 2018.2 cannot possibly support its iGPU. You need to use a newer release (the newest possibly).

Comment: So like, 2019.1?

Comment: Nevermind, I could use the latest, thanks!